# dnsmasq: Is it possible to match a domain pattern like "dev.*.*"?

Tags: dnsmasq

I'm trying to set up dnsmasq 2.79 on MacOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra).

My goal is to map all domains with the pattern `dev.*.*` to a VM. So, for example, the domain `dev.example.com` would map to the VM.

It's pretty common to do this in reverse – *i.e.*, to use the pattern `*.dev`, so that `www.example.dev` maps to the VM.

For certain logistical reasons, though, I'd prefer to use `dev.*.*`, if possible.

My questions:

1. Is this possible? If so, what syntax should I use in my `dnsmasq.conf` file?

   I considered regular expressions, but (as far as I can tell) the official version of dnsmasq doesn't support regex. There are forks which do, but I'd rather avoid those.
2. Is the syntax for `<domain>` values documented anywhere? I've Googled around, and examined [the dnsmasq man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html), but I haven't been able to find any clear documentation for the syntax of these domain strings.

Thanks!

Comment: seems not possible with latest version of dnsmasq